# Questions about ruby's nil class and rescue

Tags: ruby

Ruby Koans exercises has a file `about_nil.rb`. Below is its code:

```
def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil

begin
  nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
rescue Exception => ex
  assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class
  assert_match(/undefined method/, ex.message)
  end
end
```

What does `ex.class` mean? What is `ex` (the error type class)? Why does `ex` have a class? Also What's the difference between `assert_equal` and `assert_match`? Why does the error message need to be between `/ /`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `ex.class` mean?

It is the class of `ex`.

> What is `ex` (the error type class)?

Any potential error is captured by the `rescue` keyword. The `rescue Exception => ex` line receives that and assigns it to a local variable `ex`.

> Why does `ex` have a class?

Because `ex` is an exception object. Every object in Ruby has a class.

> What's the difference between `assert_equal` and `assert_match`?

Whether they apply equality `==` or regex match `=~` to check the test.

> Why does the error message need to be between `/ /`?

To make it a regex, as a substring would not match a string containing it.